# VirtualAlloc/VirtualFree vs Heap Functions

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

well , it's known that GlobalAlloc/GlobalFree/HeapAlloc/HeapFree APIs are managing default heaps or user defined heaps (CreateHeap) , for each heap there are segments each segment has multiple blocks.It's known The Freelist and the lookaside list are managing the free blocks in each heap.

In was reversing a piece of software and I found that is using VirtualAlloc to allocate a big chunk of memory . Basically I cannot say that it's a heap because the chunk was directly allocated from the Virtual address space and it doesn't show any signs of being a heap.
But some routines in the application will setup a custom Freelist which is itself managed by the application and it's used to define and control the free portions of that big chunk allocated using VirtualAlloc.

Can I call this chunk a HEAP as the application has setup a Freelist structure managing it ?

Comment: You can call it a banana if you want to.  What do you actually want to know?

Comment: I am actually corrupting that chunk and overwriting the flink/blink pointers setup by the application , I wanted to write a write-up about it and I'm afraid to be mistaken by calling that allocated chunk as a heap ! because it's not , it's just a chunk of memory from the VAS edited by the application so it can get just little characteristics of a heap !!

Comment: So you answered your own question, it's not a heap.

Comment: I just wanted to be sure about it , thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VirtualAlloc can be used with success to implement custom memory managers. I suppose this is what your code might be doing. It might use VirtualAlloc to reserve contiguous large address space, but it initially does not commit it, this means no physical memory is retrieved from system. Free list might point to such non committed address spaces.

VirtualAlloc is actually at the lowest level when it comes to memory management, malloc library might be actually implemented using it.

Comment: Actually the freelist will point to a committed space, because the block where it points to was committed then allocated . After being freed the application will add it to the freelist by setting the 2 pointers inside that memory portion and editing the main freelist flink and blink. So that's actually a committed memory region which is accessed whenever a portion of the big chunk is allocated or freed. Uncommitted regions are those that will be committed when no committed portions are available for allocations and those checks are all done by the application.